# Terraform - How to join elements of a nested list?

Tags: list, terraform

I have two lists - `["l","h"]`, `["a","b"]` and from that, I need to create a list like: `["la", "lb", "ha", "hb"]` - is it possible?

I tried with `setproduct()`, `flatten()` and `join()` but the closest I could get, like this:

```
> setproduct(["l","h"], ["a","b"])
[
  [
    "l",
    "a",
  ],
  [
    "l",
    "b",
  ],
  [
    "h",
    "a",
  ],
  [
    "h",
    "b",
  ],
]
#
> flatten(setproduct(["l","h"], ["a","b"]))
[
  "l",
  "a",
  "l",
  "b",
  "h",
  "a",
  "h",
  "b",
]
```

I can also join a single element:

```
> join("",setproduct(["l","h"], ["a","b"])[1])
lb
```

but yet to figure out how to get `["la", "lb", "ha", "hb"]` out of that. Any help from anyone?

-S

Comment: What version of Terraform?

Comment: ```Terraform v0.12.2
+ provider.aws v2.16.0```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using chunklist, flattern, join, and for loop,

```
> [for test in chunklist(flatten(setproduct(["l","h"], ["a","b"])), 2): join("", test)]
[
  "la",
  "lb",
  "ha",
  "hb",
]
```

Comment: thanks @RyanKim! I didn't know about the _for_ loop in terraform at all. and in this case, it can be simply done with: `[for test in setproduct(["l","h"], ["a","b"]): join("", test)]`, without using _chunklist()_ and _flatten()_

Comment: Good! 
for loop was introduced in terraform 0.12.x and i am still using v0.11.14. so I am not good at 0.12 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this is just two nested for expressions:

In the console:

```
> flatten([for i in ["l","h"]: [for j in ["a","b"]: "${i}${j}"]])
[
  "la",
  "lb",
  "ha",
  "hb",
]
```

In HCL:

```hcl
output "flat" {
  value = flatten([
    for i in ["l","h"]: [
      for j in ["a","b"]: "${i}${j}"
    ]])
}
```

Outputs:

```
Outputs:

flat = [
  "la",
  "lb",
  "ha",
  "hb",
]
```